# Spring Boot multipartfile always null

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, retrofit, multipart

I am using Spring Boot version = '1.4.0.RC1' with Spring Boot Stormpath 1.0.2.

I am trying to use multipart file upload but the MultipartFile is always null in the controller.

When I use @RequestPart("file") the info: `"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException","message":"Required request part 'file' is not present"`

When I use @RequestPart(name = "file", required = false), the part is always null.

However, if I add an HttpServletRequest argument to the controller, I can get the file part directly from the request, so I know that it is actually present.

This is the controller and in the code below `checkNotNull(part)` always succeeds and `checkNotNull(imageFile)` always fails:

```
@PostMapping("{username}/profilePhoto")
public ResponseEntity<?> saveProfilePhoto(@PathVariable("username") String username,
                                          @RequestPart(name = "file", required = false) MultipartFile imageFile,
                                          HttpServletRequest request) {
    try {
        Part part = request.getPart("file");
        checkNotNull(part);
        checkNotNull(imageFile);
    } catch (IOException | ServletException ex) {
        throw InternalServerErrorException.create();
    }

    // Transfer the multipart file to a temp file
    File tmpFile;
    try {
        tmpFile = File.createTempFile(TMP_FILE_PREFIX, null);
        imageFile.transferTo(tmpFile);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        log.error("Failed to create temp file", ex);
        throw InternalServerErrorException.create();
    }

    // Execute the use case
    updateUserProfilePhoto.execute(username, tmpFile);

    // Delete the temp file
    FileUtils.deleteQuietly(tmpFile);

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).build();
}
```

My integration test uses retrofit:

```
@Multipart
@POST("users/{username}/profilePhoto")
Call<Void> uploadProfilePhoto(@Path("username") String username,
                              @Part("file") RequestBody profilePhoto);

...

@Test
public void saveProfilePhoto_shouldSavePhoto() throws IOException {
    // Given
    String usernamme = usernames[0];
    Resource testImageResource = context.getResource("classpath:images/test_image.jpg");
    File imageFile = testImageResource.getFile();
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MediaType.parse("image/*"), imageFile);

    // When
    Response<Void> response = getTestApi().uploadProfilePhoto(usernamme, body).execute();

    // Then
    assertThat(response.code()).isEqualTo(201);
}
```

I am using auto configuration so my only custom config class configures Stormpath:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityWebAppConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.apply(stormpath());
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
This is the outgoing request. I am not sure how to enable logging in the multipart resolver itself.

```
2016-08-18 14:44:14.714 DEBUG 13088 --- [           main] c.t.server.web.testutil.TestConfig$1     : --> POST http://localhost:8080/users/user1/profilePhoto http/1.1
2016-08-18 14:44:14.714 DEBUG 13088 --- [           main] c.t.server.web.testutil.TestConfig$1     : Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=fe23ef21-3413-404c-a260-791c6921b2c6
2016-08-18 14:44:14.715 DEBUG 13088 --- [           main] c.t.server.web.testutil.TestConfig$1     : Content-Length: 181212
2016-08-18 14:44:14.715 DEBUG 13088 --- [           main] c.t.server.web.testutil.TestConfig$1     : Accept: application/json
2016-08-18 14:44:14.715 DEBUG 13088 --- [           main] c.t.server.web.testutil.TestConfig$1     : Authorization: Bearer [token]
2016-08-18 14:44:14.715 DEBUG 13088 --- [           main] c.t.server.web.testutil.TestConfig$1     : 
2016-08-18 14:44:14.735 DEBUG 13088 --- [           main] c.t.server.web.testutil.TestConfig$1     : --fe23ef21-3413-404c-a260-791c6921b2c6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: image/*
Content-Length: 180999

file data

--fe23ef21-3413-404c-a260-791c6921b2c6--

2016-08-18 14:44:14.762 DEBUG 13088 --- [           main] c.t.server.web.testutil.TestConfig$1     : --> END POST (181212-byte body)
```

Any ideas on what is happening?

Comment: Can you include what the request payload looks like? Maybe even add debug level logging to the `MultipartResolver` that you are using to see if it is interpreting the multipart component of the request?

Comment: @shawn-clark This is the outgoing request. I am not sure how to enable logging in the multipart resolver itself.


    Request headers:
    Accept: application/json
    Authorization: Bearer [auth token]
    Request body:
    --56436527-d311-4d26-8e67-27fdf6f0edb8
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
    Content-Type: image/* 
    Content-Length: 180999

    [... binary...]

    --56436527-d311-4d26-8e67-27fdf6f0edb8--

Comment: As you are using spring boot 1.4 you can use my solution and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that the problem was the way I was building my request with Retrofit.

Spring's multipart resolver requires the filename for the file to be present in content-disposition field of the part. Without this, it doesn't add the file into the multipart request.

According to the info found here: https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server, my API interface should be:

```
@Multipart
@POST("users/{username}/profilePhoto")
Call<Void> uploadProfilePhoto(@Path("username") String username,
                              @Part MultipartBody.Part profilePhoto);
```

And then when making the call in my test:

```
// Given
String usernamme = usernames[0];
Resource testImageResource = context.getResource("classpath:images/test_image.jpg");
File imageFile = testImageResource.getFile();
RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), imageFile);
MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", imageFile.getName(), requestFile);

// When
Response<Void> response = testApi.uploadProfilePhoto(usernamme, filePart).execute();
```

Comment: Glad you got it going. I was thinking the same but your sample request shows that the name is there as "file".

Comment: I figured out this about Content-Disposition yesterday after about 5 hours :/

Answer (score 5):

You have to enable the [Spring Multipart Resolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-multipart) as by default Spring doesn't enable the multipart capability.

> By default, Spring does no multipart handling, because some developers
> want to handle multiparts themselves. You enable Spring multipart
> handling by adding a multipart resolver to the web application’s
> context.

To your configuration class you would want to add the following bean:

```
@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
}
```

*** Update ***
As my previous answer was not correct based on the comments. Here is an updated example that I was able to run successfully.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class StackoverflowWebmvcSandboxApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StackoverflowWebmvcSandboxApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Controller
    public class UploadPhoto {
        @PostMapping("{username}/profilePhoto")
        public ResponseEntity<String> saveProfilePhoto(@PathVariable("username") String username,
                @RequestPart(name = "file", required = false) MultipartFile imageFile, HttpServletRequest request) {
            String body = "MultipartFile";
            if (imageFile == null) {
                body = "Null MultipartFile";
            }

            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(body);
        }
    }
}
```

It is a very basic test with no special stuff. I then created a postman request and here is the sample curl call:

```
curl -X POST -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: 17e5e6ac-3762-7d45-bc99-8cfcb6dc8cb5" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW" -F "file=@" "http://localhost:8080/test/profilePhoto"
```

The response was `MultipartFile` meaning that it wasn't null and doing a debug on that line showed that the variable was populated with the image that I was uploading.

Comment: Spring Boot Web MVC does configure a multipart resolver automatically so adding that bean is unnecessary. As a check though, I did add it but still got the same error.

Comment: Ah nice... didn't check for the AutoConfiguration for it but have since found it under `MultipartAutoConfiguration`. It looks by default to use the `StandardServletMultipartResolver`. You said you were still getting the error with the `CommonsMultipartResolver` so it seems it is more an issue with the way the request is coming in.

Answer (score 5):

Check if the following line is present in your application.properties:

```
spring.http.multipart.enabled = true
```

Comment: If you're using Spring 2.0 or greater, it's now `spring.servlet.multipart.enabled = true`

Comment: `spring.servlet.multipart.enabled` is true by default

Answer (score 4):

You have to enable the [Spring Multipart Resolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart) as by default Spring doesn't enable the multipart capability.

> By default, Spring does no multipart handling, because some developers
>   want to handle multiparts themselves. You enable Spring multipart
>   handling by adding a multipart resolver to the web application’s
>   context.

To your configuration class you would want to add the following bean:

```
@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
}
```

Since spring boot 1.4+ uses servlet 3.0+ we can leverage on `StandardServletMultipartResolver` instead of classic `CommonsMultipartResolver`

Comment: Which version of spring boot you are using?

Comment: https://github.com/rajadilipkolli/spring-mvc-showcase/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/mvc/configuration/WebMvcConfig.java#L99-L112  sample code which is working

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to my answer in this URL:
[Spring Boot multipart upload getting null file object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42732725/spring-boot-multipart-upload-getting-null-file-object/44016727#44016727)

Basically you have to avoid the default Spring configuration for multipart and avoid to set Content-type or boundary in your request header.