# Spring Boot multipart upload getting null file object

Tags: java, spring, file-upload, spring-boot

I am getting a problem while implementing multipart file upload using spring boot 1.5.2.

Here is the situation, I have a mapping to handle file upload process.While I start the spring server, it starts without any error. The problem is that I would either **able to upload the file perfectly fine** or I would **get null on all attribute in FileBucket object**.

This situation would stay forever if I do not shutdown the server.

- If it could upload, it would upload fine for the rest of the time.
- If not, it won't work until I restart the server(likely more than one
  time)

Here is the mapping.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/api/upload"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Integer>> upload(@Valid FileBucket fileBucket, BindingResult result) throws IOException {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        User user = (User) session.load(User.class, getUserId());

        Map<String, Integer> model = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println("validation errors");
            System.out.println(result);
            session.close();
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        } else {
            int documentId = saveDocument(fileBucket, user);
            model.put("documentId", documentId);
            session.close();
            return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Integer>>(model, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
}
```

And the `FileBucket` object

```
public class FileBucketConversation {

    private MultipartFile file;

    public MultipartFile getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(MultipartFile file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
}
```

I have tried few ways to implement file upload, and still having the same situation.

1. Using `StandardServletMultipartResolver`.

   ```
   @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
   public StandardServletMultipartResolver resolver() {
       return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
   }
   ```
2. Using `CommonsMultipartResolver` v1.3.2.

   ```
   @Bean(name="multipartResolver")
   public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver () {
       CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
       resolver.setMaxUploadSize(MAX_FILE_SIZE);
       return resolver;
   }
   ```

   overriding `MultipartFilter`

   ```
   @Bean
   @Order(0)
   public MultipartFilter multipartFile() {
       MultipartFilter multipartFilter = new MultipartFilter();
       multipartFilter.setMultipartResolverBeanName("multipartResolver");
       return multipartFilter;
   }
   ```
3. Enable `spring.http.multipart` in properties file

   ```
   spring.http.multipart.enabled=true
   spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=20Mb
   spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=20Mb
   ```

I really have no clue where to start looking. The problem happen occasionally, it do not happen every time I start the server but most of the time. Hoping some one could help me.

Thank you.

Comment: please share if you are able to resolve this problem..facing the same issue

Comment: I have been working a different project, I did try @Aleixs's solution but at the same time, I made a huge modification on the server and the problem never appears again. Not sure if that actually solve the problem. Sorry about that. I turned off the default multipartresolver and use CommonMultipartResolver instead.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, this is my solution:

In application.yml:

```
spring:
  http:
    multipart:
      enabled: false
```

In configuration:

```
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver;
...

@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
}
```

In RestController:

```
@PostMapping(value = "api/upload", consumes = "multipart/form-data") 
public void enablePurchase(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers,
                           FileBucketConversation fileBucketConversation) {
...
}
```

**Important:**
In your client don't use any header to define the Content-type or boundary. I'm using Angular 4 and when I remove these headers from my code it works (I only set the User token):

```
/* DON'T USE THIS:
let boundary = "ABDCE";
headers.append("Content-type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
headers.append("enctype", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
headers.append("boundary", boundary);
*/
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: does the spring:
  http:
    multipart:
      enabled: false     should be false or true?

Comment: It has to be false

Comment: any news on that? Did it work @AutoMEta? I have the same problem as you, but in my case, it only works on localhost and not on a remote server

Comment: nope..facing the same issue and instead i changed the project version to normal spring version (without the boot) and old spring version where it was working fine.

Comment: I am using springs 1.5.6 version and commons-fileupload 1.3.2. @RequestParam didn't work for me and had to use @RequestPart(value = "file", required = false). I had "multipartResolver" and all other suggested properties but I didn't have "spring: http: multipart: enabled: false". As soon as I added it everything worked. I never needed that explicit setting in my other project which is working on spring 1.3.5, hence i was totally oblivious of this flag.

Comment: thanks . This work in spring boot 1.5.3.RELEASE. "spring: http: multipart: enabled: false" is a must !!

Answer (score 1):

**Update for Spring Boot 2 and Spring 5**

`spring.http.multipart.enabled` is deprecated, so forget about it.

Registering my own beans for `MultipartConfigElement` or `MultipartResolver` broke it for me.

I ended up with a `@PostMapping` method with a single parameter, `@RequestPart(name = "file") MultipartFile file`. Adding a parameter `@RequestHeader HttpHeader headers` helped me make sure the client was sending the required header Content-Type with a boundary.

I'm using a Node client with the [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) library and [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch). Here's the client code:

```
const formData = new FormData();
const fileMetadata = {filename: fileName, contentType: 'image/png', knownLength: fs.statSync(pathToFile)};
const formData.append('file', fs.createReadStream(pathToFile), fileMetadata);
fetch(url, {method: 'POST', body: formData});
```